# java 8: how to stream an array of int, extract low bytes, and create an array of byte

Tags: java, java-stream

To interface two libraries, I need to convert an int[] array holding bytes into a byte[] array of just the low bytes. (I need to mask the ints with 0xFF and store them in a byte[] array.) I can only find examples of how to do that while converting all 4 bytes of the int, which I do not need.

As an exercise I am looking to do this with something short and efficient in pure Java 8 (i.e. valid Java 8 code without external libraries, calls, or SOUP). I tried using streams, but was unable to find a map() that worked; for example:

```
byte[] mybytarray = Arrays.asList(myintarray).stream().map(v -> v & 0xFF).collect(toList()).toArray(byte[]::new);
```

but there is the error "Cannot infer type argument(s) for  map(Function)" and I do not understand how to write the map.

Comment: You can't make a List of primitives. Look up `Arrays.stream` and primitive streams.

Comment: @user2357112 there is no byte stream.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen: Yup, so you'd need an IntStream.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, steams don't support the `byte` type directly; i.e,. there is no `ByteStream` specialization like there are for `int` and `long`<sup>1</sup>.

If you insist on using streams, a reasonably efficient solution is to use a `ByteArrayOutputStream` to collect the bytes:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos(myintarray.length);
Arrays.stream(myintarray).forEachOrdered(i -> baos.write((byte)i));
byte[] byteArray = baos.toArray();
```

This only copies the array once. A for loop and explicit array insertion is going to be better still:

```
byte[] byteArray = new byte[myintarray.length];
for (int i = 0; i < myintarray.length; i++) {
  byteArray[i] = (byte)myintarray[i];
}
```

Probably slightly more concise than the streams version, and about as fast as you'll get in Java.

If you *really insist* on a 1-liner with `Stream`s, you can get a `Byte[]` rather than a `byte[]` like so:

```
Arrays.stream(myintarray).boxed().map(Integer::byteValue)
    .collect(Collectors.toList()).toArray(new Byte[myintarray.length]);
```

This involves a crapload of boxing and you end up with a much larger and slower `Byte[]`, but hey you used a *pure Java 8* solution, right?

---

<sup>1</sup> *Combinatorial explosion* arguments notwithstanding, this has always seemed like an unfortunate omission to me, given the key nature of `byte[]` in many input/output oriented operations.

Comment: It's not an oversight; it's deliberate. They didn't want a combinatorial explosion of stream classes and methods to deal with different mixtures of primitive types. The stream types they picked were deemed sufficient.

Comment: Sure, I know _why_ they did it, and you won't hear me whining about missing `short`, `char` or `float`, but leaving `byte` out in the cold is unfortunate. It is _the_ primitive type in a way, since you can overlay everything else on an array of `byte` if you choose, and all the basic stream classes like `InputStream` operate on streams of bytes. I have frequently missed not having byte stream operations exactly because files, sockets, etc all deal on array of bytes. If I could choose only two, I'd have chosen `long` and `byte`.

Comment: ... of course, most people want `int` most of all, so I know that wouldn't really work. The combinatorial explosion thing is really a shame, it's a consequence of how Java handles primitives, but it would have been nice if they found a more elegant way around it, or at least provided wrappers for `byte[]` so that they could be exposed as `IntStream` but have efficient underlying operations. In any case, I tempered my language to "unfortunate omission" rather than "serious oversight" which seems more accurate. @user2357112

Comment: @BeeOnRope thanks for the good information about streams and bytes! Thanks also for the (what are to me) very funny end comments, given you don't know what actual restrictions I am working under, for who, or even why.  :)

Comment: Well the last comment is more an indication being "pure Java 8" isn't really well-defined? Does it mean using only language features introduced in Java 8? Certainly the `Integer` and `Byte` classes have existed since Java 1.x or whatever so that rules out pretty much everything. So the restriction seems ill-formed and arbitrary. Unlike many people who constantly challenge restrictions, I could care less _who_ you work for or _why_ you have this restriction, but the restriction itself should be made clear. @user9999999

Comment: @BeeOnRope So you couldn't care less ... but had to use ~10% of your answer to comment on it rather than just show a functional example and point out it is a bad idea because it is hard to read and use? It wasn't enough that I made a request, to avoid getting a list of all the libraries that can do this? I have to explain that "pure java 8" does not include anything which is not part of Java 8 (such as libraries, external calls, and SOUP) to avoid condescending passive aggressive replies?

Comment: To be clear I couldn't care less about _who_ you work for or _why_ you have those restrictions - which is something you mentioned in your last comment: I couldn't possibly have been referring to those in my answer yesterday. I said I do care about the nature of the _restriction itself_ since that constrains the correct answer! I understand now that you meant without using 3rd party libraries, which makes sense: I had originally read it as "using only Java 8 features like streams". In that case, the most efficient is to avoid streams at all and use a for-loop to populate an array.

Answer (score 0):

Create a byte array with the same size as the int array, and let an index counter run from 0 to the size of the byte array - 1.   Get the int value at the index counter and calculate the byte value you need and store it at the same index counter.